# set header in camel's loopDoWhile

Tags: apache-camel

It looks like set header  **currentpage_start_time_x** is only set once, although it is in the loop,
but header **currentpage_start_time** will be set multiple times.
Below is snipet of the code, could anyone give me some hints?
Thanks in advance.

```
from("direct:api-query")
        .loopDoWhile(simple("${in.header.continue}"))
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG," send to next page to \n -> {{project.query.url}}?limit={{project.query.limit}}&page=${in.header.currentPage}")
            .to("metrics:timer:simple.timer?action=start")
            // it will be set only once
            .setHeader("currentpage_start_time_x",simple(Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString()))
            .process(
                    exg->{
                        LOG.info("currentpage_start_time_x->{}" , exg.getIn().getHeader("currentpage_start_time_x"));
                        //it will be set multiple times ( as same as loop size)
                        exg.getIn().setHeader("currentpage_start_time", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    }
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

u use simple like a constant so This is a fixed constant value (or object) that is only set once during starting up the route, do not use this if you want dynamic values during routing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right!